# Resolving a Proxy Authentication Required Issue

Tags: delphi, proxy, wininet, proxy-authentication

I've written a Delphi application which requires communication with a remote web server. I pass INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG flag into the InternetOpen function to initialise my app's use of the WinINet functions and by doing so my app to retrieve the user's Internet configuration from the registry.

```
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('WebTool', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if Assigned(NetHandle) then
  begin
    try
      hConnect := InternetConnect(NetHandle, PChar(ServerName), ServerPort,
                      nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
      if Assigned(hConnect) then
      begin
        try
          // Open the request
          hRequest := HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, PChar('POST'),
                          PChar(ServerScript), nil, nil, nil,
                          HTTPOpenRequestFlags, 0);
          if Assigned(hRequest) then
          begin
```

Perhaps due to my ignorance, I believed this enabled communication with the remote web server using the user's particular Internet settings whether direct connection or via a proxy. It certainly works via my company's proxy server.

However, I've now encountered one customer for whom the above does not allow him access. He sees a "Proxy Authentication Required" (HTTP status code 407) instead.

Is this something that my app should be handling (e.g. provide a form to enter proxy authentication details and pass them with my HTTP requests)? Is there a way of picking up this information automatically?

Or is this simply down to a configuration issue that the customer's IT department can easily resolve?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: in order to get help, add the code which you are using to get the proxy information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to handle authentication, depending on what auth methods the proxy supports (it will tell you in the 407 response). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384220(VS.85).aspx